# Sympy replace angular momentum operator

Tags: sympy

I'm working right on quite complex and long equations for my PhD and I was hoping that I could use sympy in order to check my equations and obtain them faster.
These equations have Spherical Harmonics and I was hoping I could factorize the L^2 operator to replace it just with L^2.
But I tried many different things without sucess, so I did several test to find where is the problem :

```
zeta,theta,phi=sy.symbols(r"\zeta \theta \phi")

Lsqr=sy.Function(r"L^2")(theta,phi)


a=sy.Function("a")(zeta)
b=sy.Function("b")(zeta)
c=sy.Function("c")(zeta)
d=sy.Function("d")(zeta)
e=sy.Function("e")(zeta)

#first case without dividing function
test_L=e*a+b*e
Lsquare=a+b

test_L=sy.factor(test_L,Lsquare)
test_L=test_L.replace(Lsquare,Lsqr)
print("test")
print(test_L)
# result : L^2(\theta, \phi)*e(\zeta) => GOOD

#second case with dividing function

test_L=e*a/c+b*e
Lsquare=a/c+b

test_L=sy.factor(test_L,Lsquare)
test_L=test_L.replace(Lsquare,Lsqr)
print("test")
print(test_L)

# result : (a(\zeta) + b(\zeta)*c(\zeta))*e(\zeta)/c(\zeta) => BAD I would like same form has before
```

I would like to have the same form as done in the first test : L^2*c

The reason of that I have equations under the form :

```
\frac{\left(\sin{\left(\theta \right)} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta^{2}} \operatorname{Y^{m}_{l}}{\left(\theta,\phi \right)} + \cos{\left(\theta \right)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \operatorname{Y^{m}_{l}}{\left(\theta,\phi \right)}\right) \rho_{0}{\left(\zeta,\theta \right)}}{\sin{\left(\theta \right)}} + \frac{\rho_{0}{\left(\zeta,\theta \right)} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \phi^{2}} \operatorname{Y^{m}_{l}}{\left(\theta,\phi \right)}}{\sin^{2}{\left(\theta \right)}}
```

And I would like to obtain :

```
\rho_0(\zeta,\theta) L^2 Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
```

Sorry, I don t know how to edit latex formulas.

Comment: And I cannot use a factorization by \rho_0 because the terms in front of the derivative of the Spherical Harmonics are really long and not the same so I would like just to see if there are some terms that are factorizable by L^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `L^2 = a/c+b` and the pattern `a/c+b` does not appear as a single argument in the expression, the substitution fails. But if you replace `b` with `L^2 - a/c` you will have some success:

```py
>>> test_L.subs(b,Lsqr-a/c).factor()
L^2(\\theta, \\phi)*e(\\zeta)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand you explanation but in that case why is it working with a*c+b. And your solution works but it's not I am trying to achieve. It s just test to see how sympy is working. I will write a bit more give me 5 minutes

Comment: If the replacement pattern is not a leaf of the expression tree, the replacement will not be made. The expressions `(a*c + b)*x` is a Mul and one argument/leaf is `a*c + b` but in the expression `(a +b*c)*x/c` there is no argument that is `a/c + b` (though the ratio of two of the arguments, when simplified, would give that. But that sort of searching for a valid evaluation of args to give the desired target is beyond the scope of the replacement mechanisms.